# How can i configure fluent nHibernate connection properties

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Can someone tell he how i can setup my fluent nhibernate connection to always connect as follows

- SET NOCOUNT ON
- SET ARITHABORT ON
- SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON

this is what i have at the moment

```
            var fluentConfiguration = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(ConnectionString).ShowSql());

            fluentConfiguration = fluentConfiguration.Cache(c => c
                    .UseQueryCache()
                    .UseMinimalPuts()
                    .ProviderClass<HashtableCacheProvider>());
```

thanks
Niall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your can customize that in DriverConnectionProvider. Custome properties how set numer... etc is for session so you could do it using driverconnectionproperties

```
public class ContextConnectionDriver : DriverConnectionProvider
{
  public override IDbConnection GetConnection()
  {
    var conn = base.GetConnection();
    SetContext(conn);
    return conn;
  }
  private void SetContext(IDbConnection conn)
  {
    string const COMMAND_TEXT = "SET NOCOUNT ON;SET ARITHABORT ON;SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT ON;";
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       cmd.CommandText = COMMAND_TEXT;           
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}


Set the NHibernate property connection.provider to <namespace>. ContextConnectionDriver, <assembly>
,to set the namespace and assembly according to the name of your project.
```

References Nhibernate 3.0 cookbook